# HealthKit background delivery entitlements iOS 15

Tags: ios, healthkit

I'm adding Background Delivery to `HealthKit` capabilities in iOS 15. I'm seeing an issue saying I'm missing `com.apple.developer.healthkit.background-delivery` in my entitlements, this doesn't happen on iOS 14. I'm now unable to run my application and test background delivery for iOS 15.

> Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: " doesn't include the com.apple.developer.healthkit.background-delivery
> entitlement

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to re-generate the profile on the Apple developer site?

Comment: @Moose I'm unable to re-generate because I'm using a free developer account. The issue persists, I can't test my application. I can't figure out a workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Apple Developer support, it seems only **paid** developer accounts qualify for these “special” entitlements. I’m using a free developer account. Problem solved. It needs to be set in App Store Connect which doesn’t apply to me.

> The bundle ID set in the Xcode project matches the bundle ID chosen in the App Store Connect app record